# ProGuard Android - JDBC Error - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my Android App with Proguard. But I ran into a strange issue and I hope one of you guys would is able to help me out.

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep public class com.mysql.** {*;}  
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** {*;} 
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn com.mysql.**
-libraryjars /libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar
-dontshrink
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

So as you can see I already added that mysql JDBC lib as libary and as class which should be kept. But when I try to compile the project to an .apk file I am ending up with this strange Error. I don't know why as it shouldn't even be touched, according to my config.

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Note: there were 508 duplicate class definitions.
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
Class       = [com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl]
Method      = [isReadOnly(Z)Z]
Instruction = [77] iload v4
Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
Class       = [com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl]
Method      = [isReadOnly(Z)Z]
Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
Error: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating Proguard to the new 5.0 version.